# "Transform variable into final one element array". error on RecyclerView Scroll Listener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I got error

> Transform variable into final one element array

while I am using `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`. why this error?

[image]

Comment: Try to disclare justCheck Global and use it

Comment: how to declare it? please answer that

Comment: can you share the image where you define justCheck ?

Comment: final boolean justcheck=false;

Comment: define this on start of this file where you define other variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `boolean justCheck;` to the top, to declare as a Global Variable.

Comment: wow, thanks for help. But questions is why this required in a class? any declaration please.. thanks again